# Keep getting "no member function declared" error, even though it is declared and defined

Tags: c++, inheritance, cmake

I have a fairly simple situation, and the fact that I can't cope with it drives me crazy.

I have a class that is declared as follows:

```
// inc/Services/Specific/ReviewRetriever.h
#include "../../ReviewRetriever.h"
class Specific_ReviewRetriever : public ReviewRetriever
{
public:
    Specific_ReviewRetriever(Service* service);
    ~Specific_ReviewRetriever() = default;
};
```

Implementation of the class goes as follows:

```
// src/Services/TrustedShops/ReviewRetriever.cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "Service.h"
#include "Services/Specific/ReviewRetriever.h"


Specific_ReviewRetriever::Specific_ReviewRetriever(Service* service) :
    ReviewRetriever(service)
{

}

std::string Specific_ReviewRetriever::prepare_update_link(std::string link)
{

}

std::vector<int> Specific_ReviewRetriever::parse_response(boost::property_tree::ptree responseXML)
{

}
```

This class inherits from the class that is declared as follows:

```
// inc/ReviewRetriever.h
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

#include "Review.h"

class Service;

class ReviewRetriever
{
public:
    ~ReviewRetriever() = default;
    void retrieve(std::vector<Review> & reviews);
protected:
    ReviewRetriever(Service* service);
    virtual std::string prepare_update_link(std::string link) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<Review> parse_response(boost::property_tree::ptree responseXML) = 0;
    Service* _service;
};
```

And this class on its part is defined as follows:

```
// src/ReviewRetriever.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

#include "Review.h"
#include "ReviewRetriever.h"

void ReviewRetriever::retrieve(std::vector<Review> & reviews)
{

}
```

So a fairly simple class and another one that inherits from it. But when I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
no ‘std::string Specific_ReviewRetriever::prepare_update_link(std::string)’
member function declared in class ‘Specific_ReviewRetriever’
```

So, even though I got implementation of the class, the compiler doesn't seem to notice it (even though it sees that the class Specific_ReviewRetriever inherits from ReviewRetriever, it refuses to recognize its methods).

I build with cmake and here is the relevant part:

```
// src/CMakeLists.txt
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources *.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_target PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/)
```

(here `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` is `src/../`).

So as I mentioned, implementation and declaration of the classes is present, and yet compilation fails. I understand that the problem may not be on the surface, but I am really clueless where to start to track the error, maybe you have a piece of advice on that.

In case this excerpt of code is insufficient, entire code lies [here](https://github.com/haemhweg/reputation).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You still have to declare the functions that you're overriding in the derived class:

```
class Specific_ReviewRetriever : public ReviewRetriever
{
public:
    Specific_ReviewRetriever(Service* service);
    ~Specific_ReviewRetriever() = default;
    // Overrides:
    virtual std::string prepare_update_link(std::string link);
    virtual std::vector<int> Specific_ReviewRetriever::parse_response(boost::property_tree::ptree responseXML);
};
```